# SQL requirement : get common patterned columns join from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

table1:

```
col:
20kasi
30kasi
40eswar
00eswar
```

table2:

```
col:
00kasi
05kasi
06kasi
03eswar
44eswar
```

I want to join these two by their name by ignoring digits  , so that other columns i can get.

```
select  {something from each tables}
  from table1, table2
 where t1.col1 = t2.col2
```

It should show:

```
col             {other colums from one of tables after join}

kasi            ----            ----- \n
eswar           ----            -----
```

This is not having proper syntax. but I want like this .  Any suggestions??

Comment: you most likely forgot to "name alias" your tables 1 and 2 (if it is like you stated above)

Answer (score 0):

If all strings have exactly two digits, you could use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 inner join table2
     on SUBSTRING(table1.col, 3)=SUBSTRING(table2.col, 3)
```

If number of digits can vary, or if they are in different positions, since MySql doesn't support regexp you could use something like this:

```
    SELECT *
FROM table1 inner join table2
     on
        Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(table1.col,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','') =
        Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(table2.col,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','')
```

(it doesn't look very nice, but it should work)

Answer (score 0):

you have always first 2 characters as digits? if yes then this will work

```
select  {something from each tables}
  from table1 t1, table2 t2
 where substr(t1.col1,3,length(t1.col1)) = substr(t2.col2,3,length(t2.col2))
```